# Webclient - refresh API key on unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I'm looking for solution how to properly implement token refreshing mechanism.
A token should be changed after we got 401, or 403 http status code from external API. I'd like to call login endpoint to obtain a valid token, save the token into database and try again with the new token.

Currently, I'm having problem with reactor and streams. Below are two methods that contains core functionality.

**register** method (external call)

```java
public Mono<Void> register(UserConfiguration configuration) {
        return externalClient.post()
                             .uri("http://example.com")
                             .body(Mono.just(new SomeRequest()), SomeRequest.class)
                             .header(AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN_HEADER, token)
                             .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> handleResponse(clientResponse, Void.class, configuration))
                             .retryWhen(Retry.max(5)
                                             .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> log.info("Unauthorized request"))
                                             .filter(UnauthorizedException.class::isInstance))
                             .then();
    }
```

**handleResponse** method

```java
private <R> Mono<R> handleResponse(ClientResponse clientResponse, Class<R> clazz, Configuration configuration, ) {
        if (clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(clazz);
        } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) || clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)) {
            return authenticationService.refreshToken(configuration).flatMap(conf -> Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException()));
        } else {
            return clientResponse.createException()
                                 .flatMap(Mono::error);
        }
    }
```

`register` is responsible for calling external API. `handleResponse` take care of handling response status, and when there is `unauthorized` response, the method invokes `authenticationService` in order to obtain a new token and save the token into db (`UserConfiguration`). Retry detects an exception instance and when there is problem with a token, it enforces the stream going again. Unfortunately, `register` method uses the same instance of `UserConfiguration` so values there are outdated as well as token is not valid anymore.

What would be the better approach? Now I can see the only workaround to start a stream from getting `UserConfiguration`, so on retry we will have the latest state of db. It seems to work, but it's not perfect from a performance view.

Answer (score 0):

Might be late, but in case it helps someone else: you could use the `onErrorResume` method to filter for 401 and 403 HTTP responses and in those cases, renew the token, save it in the database and call the register method with the new user configuration.

Comment: Could you provide an example for this?